# Disabling <action> in plugin develoipement

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In my application have a menu named Search, it is having sub menu named "Text" and the text sub menu also has a sub menu in that there is an action named 'Package' i.e., is created as action. this search menu is common for all perspectives.

i want to disable that action 'Packages' for particular particular perspective how to do that?

please help me.following is the code for menu creation and action

```
 <menu
               id="textSearchSubMenu"
               label="Text"
               path="org.eclipse.search.menu/fileSearchContextMenuActionsGroup">
            <groupMarker
                  name="group2">
            </groupMarker>
         </menu>
         <action
               class="com.chinna.search.SPXTextSearchAction"
               id="com.chinna.builder.SearchAction"
               label="Packages"
               menubarPath="org.eclipse.search.menu/textSearchSubMenu/group2"
               pulldown="false"
               retarget="false"
               style="push">

           <enablement>
               <objectClass
                     name="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
               </objectClass>

            </enablement>

         </action>
```

Comment: Show us how you are creating this menu.

Comment: @greg-449 i have added the code.please take a look

Comment: I assume this is the `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus`  extension point which is **deprecated**. You can only set the visibility of the whole `objectContribution` or `viewerContribution`. The `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point give better control of visibility.

Comment: @greg-449 is it possible through code ?

Comment: @greg-449 i want visibility control only on my action

Comment: @greg-449 is it possible to give the pespective information inside    <enablement> tag

Comment: @greg-449 no that is in action set extension